# data.table 1.8.x mean() function auto removing NA?

Tags: r, data.table, mean, na, na.rm

Today I found out a bug in my program due to `data.table` auto remove `NA` for `mean`

for example:

```
> a<-data.table(a=c(NA,NA,FALSE,FALSE), b=c(1,1,2,2))
> a

> a[,list(mean(a), sum(a)),by=b]
   b V1 V2
1: 1  0 NA // Why V1 = 0 here? I had expected NA
2: 2  0  0


> mean(c(NA,NA,FALSE,FALSE))
[1] NA
> mean(c(NA,NA))
[1] NA
> mean(c(FALSE,FALSE))
[1] 0
```

Is this the intended behaviour?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This isn't intended. Looks like a problem with optimization ...

```
> a[,list(mean(a), sum(a)),by=b]
   b V1 V2
1: 1  0 NA
2: 2  0  0
> options(datatable.optimize=FALSE)
> a[,list(mean(a), sum(a)),by=b]
   b V1 V2
1: 1 NA NA
2: 2  0  0
>
```

Investigated and fixed in v1.8.9, soon to be on CRAN.  From [NEWS](https://r-forge.r-project.org/scm/viewvc.php/pkg/NEWS?view=markup&root=datatable) :

> mean() in j has been optimized since v1.8.2 but wasn't respecting na.rm=TRUE (the default). Many thanks to Colin Fang for reporting. Test added.

The new feature in v1.8.2 was :

> mean() is now automatically optimized, #1231. This can speed up grouping by 20 times when there are a large number of groups. See [wiki point 3](http://rwiki.sciviews.org/doku.php?id=packages%3acran%3adata.table), which is no longer needed to know. Turn off optimization by setting options(datatable.optimize=0).