# Getting NA when summarizing by columns in data.table

Tags: r, data.table, mean, na

I'm trying to summarize (take the mean) of various columns based on a single column within a data.table.

Here's a toy example of my data and the code I used that shows the problem I'm having:

```
library(data.table)
a<- data.table(
  a=c(1213.1,NA,113.41,133.4,121.1,45.34),
  b=c(14.131,NA,1.122,113.11,45.123,344.3),
  c=c(101.2,NA,232.1,194.3,12.12,7645.3),
  d=c(11.32,NA,32.121,94.3213,1223.1,34.1),
  e=c(1311.32,NA,12.781,13.2,2.1,623.2),
  f=c("A", "B", "B", "A", "B", "X"))
a
setkey(a,f) # column "f" is what I want to summarize columns by

a[, lapply(.SD, mean), by=f, .SDcols=c(1:4)] # I just want to summarize first 4 columns
```

The output of the last line:

```
> a[, lapply(.SD, mean), by=f, .SDcols=c(1:4)]
 f a b c d
1: A 673.25 63.6205 147.75 52.82065
2: B NA NA NA NA
3: X 45.34 344.3000 7645.30 34.10000
```

Why are B entries `NA`? Shouldn't `NA` be ignored in the calculation of the mean? I think I found a similar issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18571774/data-table-auto-remove-na-in-by-for-mean-function), but perhaps this is different and/or I've got the syntax messed up.

If this isn't possible in `data.table`, I'm open to other suggestions.

Comment: To ignore `NA`s, you need the argument `na.rm=TRUE`. Try `a[, lapply(.SD, mean, na.rm=TRUE), by=f, .SDcols=c(1:4)]`

Comment: ah. so simple. can you write that up? I'll give you the points

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In R, the default behavior of the `mean()` function is to output `NA` if there are missing values. To ignore `NA`s in the mean calculation, you need to set the argument `na.rm=TRUE`. `lapply` takes in additional arguments to the function it is passed, so for your problem, you can try

`a[, lapply(.SD, mean, na.rm=TRUE), by=f, .SDcols=c(1:4)]`

Comment: Sorry, but why is this not a `data.table` question (I rolled back your tag edit to the Q)? :-O

Comment: Because it is mere coincidence that this behaviour was experienced within a data.table; even without `library(data.table)` the mean of a column containing `NA` is still `NA`.

Comment: @Hugh, it helps (future) users having the same question identify this answer quickly with the data.table tag. The question is titled "data.table gives ...". It'd be hard for people who don't really understand what's going on to search the entire R tag.